# Prolog: how to non-uniformly randomly select a element from a list?

Tags: random, prolog

Does anyone have any Prolog code to non-uniformly select a random element from a list?

I want to replicate the functionality of [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) when given the probabilities associated with each entry in the input list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found nothing useful in `library(random)`.

Here's my implementation `choice(Xs, Ps, Y)`:

```
choice([X|_], [P|_], Cumul, Rand, X) :-
    Rand < Cumul + P.
choice([_|Xs], [P|Ps], Cumul, Rand, Y) :-
    Cumul1 is Cumul + P,
    Rand >= Cumul1,
    choice(Xs, Ps, Cumul1, Rand, Y).
choice([X], [P], Cumul, Rand, X) :-
    Rand < Cumul + P.

choice(Xs, Ps, Y) :- random(R), choice(Xs, Ps, 0, R, Y).
```

It works by recursively building the [cumulative probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) from the probabilities given in `Ps`, and checking if the random number `R` is below that.

Note: to function correctly the probabilities `Ps` must sum to 1, no check is made to warn you if that is not the case.

Example:

```
?- choice([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.7], Y).
Y = 3 .

?- choice([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.7], Y).
Y = 1 .

?- choice([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.7], Y).
Y = 2 .

?- choice([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.7], Y).
Y = 3 .

?- choice([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.7], Y).
Y = 2 .

?- choice([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.7], Y).
Y = 3 .

?- choice([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.7], Y).
Y = 3 .

?- choice([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.7], Y).
Y = 3 .

?- choice([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.7], Y).
Y = 3 .

?- choice([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.7], Y).
Y = 3 .

?- choice([1,2,3], [0.1,0.2,0.7], Y).
Y = 3 .

...
```